# I want to display random images in background but the code is not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, random

It just displays a blank background, with nothing in it.
I have tried the code below, saw this on stackoverflow only, but cannot seem to get it to work. Please help. The routes are correct.

```
class Landing extends Component {
  render() {

    var images = ['1.gif','2.gif','3.gif','4.gif','5.webp','6.gif','7.gif']

    return (
      <div className="landing" style = {{background: `url("./img/${images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]}")`}} >
        <div className="dark-overlay landing-inner text-light">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h1 className="display-3 mb-4">Developer Connector</h1>
                <p className="lead">
                  Create a developer profile/portfolio, share posts and get help
                  from other developers
                </p>
                <br/>
                <Link to="/register" className="btn btn-lg btn-info mr-2">
                  Sign Up
                </Link>
                <Link to="/login" className="btn btn-lg btn-light">
                  Login
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Landing;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code maybe is string with webpack.
you should use `require`
you kan do like this

```
var images = [
{
uri: require('./img/1.gif'),
title: 'title',
alt: 'alt'
},
{
uri: require('./img/2.gif'),
title: 'title',
alt: 'alt'
}
]
```